# Adapting the Contoso University Instructor Page to have sorting and filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages, paging

I have been working through the [Contoso University tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) I am trying to add filtering/sorting and paging to the instructor index page.

I have been successful in getting the filtering and sorting to work, i cannot though get the paging to work any tips on what i'm doing wrong would be very helpful.
Also  any tips on how to include Course in the search box would be much appreciated.

here is the code that works for the sorting and filtering

```
using ContosoUniversity.Models;
using ContosoUniversity.Models.SchoolViewModels;  // Add VM
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Pages.Instructors
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ContosoUniversity.Data.SchoolContext _context;
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public IndexModel(ContosoUniversity.Data.SchoolContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _context = context;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public InstructorIndexData InstructorData { get; set; }
        public int InstructorID { get; set; }
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string NameSort { get; set; }
        public string DateSort { get; set; }
        public string CurrentFilter { get; set; }
        public string CurrentSort { get; set; }

        public IList<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(int? id, int? courseID, string sortOrder, string searchString)
        {
            InstructorData = new InstructorIndexData();
            InstructorData.Instructors = await _context.Instructors
                .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
                .Include(i => i.Courses)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Department)
                .OrderBy(i => i.LastName)
                .ToListAsync();

            if (id != null)
            {
                InstructorID = id.Value;
                Instructor instructor = InstructorData.Instructors
                    .Where(i => i.ID == id.Value).Single();
                InstructorData.Courses = instructor.Courses;
            }

            if (courseID != null)
            {
                CourseID = courseID.Value;
                IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments = await _context.Enrollments
                    .Where(x => x.CourseID == CourseID)
                    .Include(i => i.Student)
                    .ToListAsync();
                InstructorData.Enrollments = Enrollments;
            }

            NameSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            DateSort = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            CurrentFilter = searchString;

            IQueryable<Instructor> instructorsIQ = from s in _context.Instructors
                                             select s;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                instructorsIQ = instructorsIQ.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString));

            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    instructorsIQ = instructorsIQ.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    instructorsIQ = instructorsIQ.OrderBy(s => s.HireDate);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    instructorsIQ = instructorsIQ.OrderByDescending(s => s.HireDate);
                    break;
                default:
                    instructorsIQ = instructorsIQ.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
            }

            InstructorData.Instructors = await instructorsIQ
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
                .Include(i => i.Courses)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Department)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

When i change the IList to a PaginatedList

```
  public PaginatedList<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }

        //public IList<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
```

and change the bottom section to a paginated list ,  the sorting filtering and paging all stop working,

```
            InstructorData.Instructors = await instructorsIQ
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
                .Include(i => i.Courses)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Department)
                .ToListAsync();

 Instructors = await PaginatedList<Instructor>
                .CreateAsync(instructorsIQ
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
                .Include(i => i.Courses)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Department), pageIndex ??1,pageSize);
```

i believe it is in the InstructorData.Instructors  vs Instructors but i cannot seem to get it to work

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).